# How to get instance of a service without injecting it into the constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created an interface say

```
public interface IMyService
{
    void SomeFun();
}
```

Implementation

```
class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void SomeFun();
}
```

Startup.cs injection

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
```

I am getting the instance of IMyService in the controller through injection in the constructor. All good till here.

I want to retrieve the instance of IMyService in a normal method. I used to do something similar in java using ApplicationContext. Is it possible to do the same in C# ASP.NET Core? If so, how?

Comment: Inject a `IServiceProvider`. You can then call `.CreateScope()` in your method to create a scope which you can use to get the service you want with `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();` Don't forget to dispose your scope :) 
If this doesn't answer your question, please define _normal method_. Where is that method?

Comment: What you also could do is property injection (at least if you are using Autofac or similar). Another way is injecting a factory into the constructor and resolving a desired instance within the method.

Comment: I have a static class 
```
static class SomeClass
{
      public static void Foo()
      {
             //I need instance of IMyService here
      }
}

Comment: create  a private variable of type IMyService in the controller then in the controller constructor pass the appropriate Service , then use the injector variable in your method. Or use simple injector it is more easy to userstand